# Which One is the Best Way to Create Training Sequences for LSTM-based Class Prediction on Time-series Data?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, time-series, lstm, pytorch

Let's say I have time-series data in the following way. I need to create training sequences of a fixed length as an input to my LSTM model on PyTorch.

```
# Time, Bitrate, Class
  0.2,  312,     1
  0.3,  319      1
  0.5,  227      0
  0.6,  229      0   
  0.7,  219      0    
  0.8,  341      1    
  1.0,  401      2
```

Once trained, the model should be able to predict classes of test data without classes. I am not sure how to create the training sequences. Let's say I define a sequence_length = 3 for the data snippet above. I have two approaches:

1. By shifting a window of sequence_length. In this case, the sequences:

```
# Sequence,                    Label of the Sequence
  [(312,1), (319,1), (227,0)]  0
  [(319,1), (227,0), (229,0)]  0
  [(227,0), (229,0), (219,0)]  0
  [(229,0), (219,0), (341,1)]  1
  [(219,0), (341,0), (401,2)]  2
```

The label of the first sequence is 0 (since the last element's class is 0). However, this seems not okay, because even if the last label is 0, the former two are not.

2. Fetching class by class up to sequence_length. if any of them is less than the sequence_length, I pad with the last element (since all tensors should have the same shape):

```
# Sequence,                   Label of the Sequence
 [(312,1), (319,1), (319,1)]  1   <- padded with the last element (319,1)
 [(227,0), (229,0), (219,0)]  0
 [(341,1), (341,1), (341,1)]  1   <- padded with the last element (341,1)
 [(401,2), (401,2), (401,2)]  2   <- padded with the last element (401,2)
```

Instead of right-padding with the last element, would zero padding from the left make more sense? If so, do I need to do something to make LSTM ignore those padded zeros?

Thanks!

Comment: Frankly, class is relevant to sequence Nikos. The data above is just an example to simplify my question. In the actual data, class distribution throughout the experiment is correlated with time.

Comment: Then using a training sequence of back step n=1 (use current sample to predict next one) might be the best approach. Since for a time delay of 1, there is no padding issue nor class difference issue

Comment: Do you mean approach 1? If so, in that case, I would have a mixed sequence such as [100001] -> since the last element's label in this sequence is '1', the system will label this sequence as '1'. However, most of the elements in this sequence have the label '0'. This is why I suspected this approach.

Comment: No I mean a training sequence of only one sample (delay =1)

Comment: In this approach, for n-th bitrate data, do I need to use the n-th class as a label, or (n+1)-th class? I mean, considering the second row of the first table above, do I need to assign the class label as '1' or as '0' for the sample '319' ?

Comment: On considering this more carefuly, you can use any training sequence (with arbitrary delay, not simply 1) meaning you can use up to n previous samples to predict the next sample. Class will be the class of the next sample, regardless of how many delay samples are used to predict this. I dont see any real problem

Comment: Thanks Nikos! I will consider your advice.