# What kind of Neural Network should I build to classify each instance of a time series sequence?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, lstm, pytorch

Let's say, I have the time-series dataset below-left. I would like to train a model in such a way that if I feed the model with an input like below-right, it should be able to classify each sample with the correct class label.

```
    Training Sequence:              Test Sequence:

Time,   Bitrate,   Class           Time,   Bitrate    Predicted Class
 0,       312,       1              0,       234      -----> 0
 0.3,     319,       1              0.2,     261      -----> 0
 0.5,     227,       0              0.4,     277      -----> 0
 0.6,     229,       0              0.7,     301      -----> 1 
 0.7,     219,       0              0.8,     305      -----> 1
 0.8,     341,       1              0.9,     343      -----> 1 
 0.9,     281,       0              1.0,     299      -----> 0 
          ...                                ...
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure to understand correctly your question, if all your samples are time independent, then just train a regular perceptron. If you want to take time into account and give your classifier a memory, then you can have a look at LSTM networks since they implement a time memory.

Comment: Actually, my samples are time-dependent. That's why I am not able to build a regular perception model. I have already tried to use LSTM but faced with severe overfitting. I explained my methodology here (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/93579/which-one-is-the-best-way-to-create-training-sequences-for-lstm-based-class-pred) but couldn't find an answer. How should I arrange my training sequences for my case? Thanks!

Comment: I am unfortunatly not very familiar with LSTM and time memory networks, so i can't help you much there. An idea to explore could be as you mentionned sending 3 or 5 previous values to your network when forecasting a value class. But i would rather use zero padding with a **constant time scale** as the network should learn to ignore the 0s. Or maybe create some kind of state with the result of the previous computation from the network to send it again into the network (this is not easily done tho).

Comment: Thanks Ubikuity! I will consider your advice.